# why does my code get the "expected } before numeric constant" error? (C coding)

Tags: c

I have an idea for a RayCaster game (more like, my first RayCaster game). I have just finished the 2D map, so I was about to work on the Pseudo 3D Part of the game, but upon compiling it to test the 2D map, hold and behold the `"expected } before numeric constant"` error appeared. I tried doing what the error told me to, but nothing happened!

What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Note: it happened on that square of 0 and 1s that were supposed to be the 2D map 0 = empty 1 = block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float px,py; //player position

void drawPlayer()
{
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    glPointSize(8);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(px,py);
    glEnd();
}

int mapX=8,mapY=8,mapS=64;
int map[]=
{
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
};

void drawMap2D()
{
    int x,y,xo,yo;
    for(y=0;y<mapY;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<mapX;x++)
        {
            if(map[y*mapX+x]==1) {
                glColor3f(1,1,1);
            }
            else{
                glColor3f(0,0,0);
            }
            xo=x*mapS; yo=y*mapS;
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2i(xo    , yo   );
            glVertex2i(xo    ,yo+mapS);
            glVertex2i(xo+mapS, yo+mapS);
            glVertex2i(xo+mapS, yo    );
            glEnd();
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawMap2d();
    drawPlayer();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void buttons(unsigned char key,int x, int y)
{
    if(key=='a') { px-=5;}
    if(key=='d') { px+=5;}
    if(key=='w') { py-=5;}
    if(key=='s') { py+=5;}
    if(key=='A') { px-=5;}
    if(key=='D') { px+=5;}
    if(key=='W') { py-=5;}
    if(key=='S') { py+=5;}
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3,0);
    gluOrtho2D(0,1024,512,0);
    px=300; py=300;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024,512);
    glutCreateWindow("Meu Jogo 3D");
    init();
    glutKeyboardFunc(buttons);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Each line in the matrix of 0 and 1 has to end with a comma

Comment: @SteveFriedl that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @SteveFriedl it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple syntax error in your map:

```
int map[] = {
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
};
```

Each item has to be separated by a comma, but each line of numbers (except the last) should have one there too; each line-ending `1` is followed directly by the `1` on the start of the next line.

Also, recommend you consider a `switch` statement in the buttons:

```
void buttons(unsigned char key,int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
      case 'a': case 'A': px -= 5; break;
      case 'd': case 'D': px += 5; break;   
      case 'w': case 'W': py -= 5; break;
      case 's': case 'S': py += 5; break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

There are different ways to do this, but a list of if/else is not optimal.

Comment: thanks but... adding commas to the end of every line of 0's and 1's INCLUDING the last one worked, thanks for the help nonetheless ;)

Comment: @OGuiBlindao some compilers might reject adding one after the last item

Comment: The final comma is not necessary, it’s not separating values, but C allows this as a convenience.

Comment: lol i just came back to my old stack overflow posts and realised that i made a yansim lmfao (if you dont get it, yansim is a game with awful code, and one of the memes regarding it is the if else vs switch, since the game performance is really dragged down by that mistake)